# class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zu not found

Tags: android, firebase

After updating all dependencies to their latest version, error persists.

Build Gradle(app):

```
repositories {

    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

Build.gradle (Project):

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
}
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = trueapply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error after building project:

```
error: cannot access zu
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zu not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Degrade Some versions and add maven url in both repositories.**

Build Gradle(app):

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    }
}
```

Build.gradle (Project):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.**.******"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

In manifest file:

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```